Largest inscribed parallelepiped of the convex set defined by partial sum of Fourier series
Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the set consisting of all $(2n+1)$-dimensional real vectors $\mathbf{x}=\left( a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n\right)^{\intercal}$ satisfying
$$
\left|  f_{\mathbf{x}}(t) \right|\le 1, \forall t\in[0,1],
$$
where the function $f_{\mathbf{x}}(t)\triangleq a_0+\sum_{m=1}^n \left(a_m\cos(2\pi mt)+b_m\sin(2\pi m t)\right)$. It is straightforward to see that $\mathcal{X}$ is convex and centrally symmetric.
My question is how to find the largest inscribed parallelepiped of $\mathcal{X}$. Comments on other geometric properties of $\mathcal{X}$ are welcome as well.

This set is invariant under a one-parametric family of isometries which can be seen by substituting $t\mapsto t - t_0$.
